# How to send a welcome mail after user verifying his email with laravel?

Tags: laravel

when user confirm his email, he was been redirected to login page , after this i want a welcome mail been send to this new user !! but i failed to do that , i want the user don't authentified automatically after email verification! how can i get the client email ?

```
public function showLoginForm(Request $request)
{
    if(session()->has('verified') && (session('verified') == 1))
        Mail::to($client->email)->send(new ConfirmEmailUpdate($client));
    return view('client.auth.login');
}
```

Comment: but how i know who is the user how just verified his email ? because th redirect url is the login page !!

Comment: this link is for email verifcation , but me i want to do actions after the verification is complete and the user is redirected to login page without authentified automatically

Comment: i find a solution by crating an event listener , see the solution below

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In `app\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php` I added

```
 protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified::class => [
        App\Listeners\ClientWelcomeListener::class,
    ],
];
```

Then I ran the command `php artisan make:listener ClientWelcomeListener` which created the listener in `app/Listeners/ClientWelcomeListener.php`

In which I could use

```php
$user->notify(new WelcomeEmail());
```